# Associativity of product sigma fields.

Tags: measure-theory

**Defn:** Let $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ be two fields in $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ respectively. The product field of $\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2$ is defined to be the set of all finite unions of disjoint rectangles $D \times S$ where $D \in \mathcal{F}_1$ and $S \in \mathcal{F}_2$.

When $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ are $\sigma$-fields, then the product sigma field is defined to be be $\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 =\sigma(\mathcal{F}_1\times \mathcal{F}_2)$; i.e the minimal sigma algebra over $\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2$.

I want to show that $\mathcal{F_1}\otimes (\mathcal{F}_2 \otimes \mathcal{F}_3) = \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F_2} \otimes \mathcal{F}_3$; which I believe is equivalent to showing that $\sigma(\mathcal{F_1} \times \sigma(\mathcal{F}_2 \times \mathcal{F}_3) = \sigma(\mathcal{F}_1\times \mathcal{F}_2\times \mathcal{F}_3)$. For the inclusion $\subseteq$, does it suffice to show that $\mathcal{F}_1 \times \sigma(\mathcal{F}_2 \times \mathcal{F}_3) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{F_1} \times \mathcal{F}_2 \times \mathcal{F}_3)$. Because then as the minimal sigma field the inclusion would follow? Does the attempt below make sense or am I misunderstanding the structure of the product sigma fields. Thanks in advance for the clarification.

**Attempt:** Let $A \in \mathcal{F}_1 \times \sigma(\mathcal{F_2}\times \mathcal{F}_3)$. By definition this means that $A = \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$ where $A_i$ are disjoint sets of the form $A_i = D_1^{(i)} \times D_2^{(i)}$ with $D_1^{(i)} \in \mathcal{F}_1$ and $D_2^{(i)} \in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_2 \times \mathcal{F}_3)$. then by definition of $D_2^{(i)}$ it follows that for all $1 \leq i \leq n$ we have that
$$
D_2^{(i)} = \bigcup_{j=1}^m H_1^{(j)} \times H_2^{(j)},
$$
with $H_1^{(j)} \in \mathcal{F}_2$ and $H_2^{(j)} \in \mathcal{F}_3$. But then it follows that
$$
A = \bigcup_{i=1}^n D_1^{(i)} \times \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^m H_1^{(j)} \times H_2^{(j)} \right)= \bigcup_{i=1}^n \bigcup_{j=1}^m D_1^{(i)} \times H_1^{(j)} \times H_2^{(j)}.
$$
Because the $A_i$ were disjoint it follows that the family $\{D_1^{(i)}\times H_1^{(j)}\times H_2^{(j)}, 1 \leq i \leq n, 1\leq j \leq m\}$ is disjoint, and therefore this is a finite union of disjoint rectangles from $\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2 \times \mathcal{F}_3$ and so $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2 \times \mathcal{F}_3)$. Therefore we get that $\mathcal{F}_1 \times \sigma(\mathcal{F}_2 \times \mathcal{F}_3) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{F_1} \times \mathcal{F}_2 \times \mathcal{F}_3)$, and so $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_1 \times \sigma(\mathcal{F}_2 \times \mathcal{F}_3)) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{F_1} \times \mathcal{F}_2 \times \mathcal{F}_3)$ by properties of the *minimal* $\sigma$-field.

**Edit:** After some thinking I think the distribution of the $\times$ over the unions in the last equation is wrong. How would I go about proving the statement?